# Populating UISearchBar with String from PrepareForSegue with CoreData/NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview, uisearchbar, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a simple application which is a table view (TV1) that gets populated by the user tapping the plus button in the navigation bar. The user gets taken to an Add Entry screen where tapping on the "name" text field brings up another Table View (TV2) for the user to add existing entries, search for existing entries or add a new entry. This works really well and delegates ensures that what I select in the new Table view (TV2) populates the Name Text Field.

What I want to achieve is the other way around also; if a user has the name text field already populated and clicks on it to bring up the TV2, I want the search bar to already be populated with the string that was passed through while ensuring the searching still works.

For example, if I have the nameTextField with John, when I click on the nameTextField and get taken to the TV2, I want the searchBar.text to say John, but also for the searching to now only show entries with John in the name, just like it would be if I start typing the name John.

I am using Core Data and NSFetchedResultsController.

In the prepaeForSegue of the Add Entry, I am doing this:

```
if ([self.nameTextField.text length] > 0)
{
    [envylopeNameTextFieldTableViewController setSelectedName:self.nameTextField.text];
}
```

In the TV2, the setSelectedName method is:

```
- (void)setSelectedName:(NSString *)selectedName
{
    _selectedName = selectedName;
    self.nameAddSearchBar.text = selectedName; 
    [self searchBar:self.nameAddSearchBar textDidChange:selectedName];
}
```

The last line in there is a trial by me because that method is what gets called when I start searching, so I thought I could call that. I tried it without it and with self.nameAddSearchBar.text = self.selectedName and _selectedName and nothing; the searchBar does not get populated.

With a breakpoint, I can see that selectedName = John and _selectedName = John, but self.nameAddSearchBar.text = nil.

I can imagine I'm one or two lines of code away, but I'm just not sure how to proceed.

Any assistance would be really great.

Thanks,

Comment: In your setSelectedName method try [self.nameAddSearchBar setText:selectedName];   I have occasionally had issues where using the .syntax didn't work but using a method call did. You could also move that assignment into prepareForSegue to see if it works there. For instance: envylopeNameTextFieldTableViewController.nameAddSearchBar.text = self.nameTextField.text;

Comment: @digitalHound many thanks for your reply and both approaches made sense. However, both didn't seem to work - with the same results; I'm wondering if I should be calling something similar.. I know it's close!

Comment: Is your search bar added in the storyboard or in code? Could it be possible the search bar is not instantiated yet?

Comment: It's set in storyboard, but hmm.. that could be a good point. I mean the viewDidLoad is assigning the searchBar delegate, but it is very possible that it's perhaps not being instantiated yet.. sorry for the basic questions (i'm still fairly new to iOS programming).. how would I go about making sure the searchBar is instantiated earlier?

Comment: On your breakpoint you can hover over "self" and look at the properties, it should tell you the value of the property or if its null.

Comment: Since you know that your _selectedName ivar is set to "John" you could move the search bar assignment from the setter into viewDidLoad where your delegate is set. self.nameAddSearchBar.text = self.selectedName;

Comment: I think that's probably it. Since the search bar is part of the "view", it may not be available until "viewDidLoad". You can set the property with the right value and then update the view (search bar.txt) once it's loaded (in viewDidLoad).

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: @digitalHound Many thanks for the messages and that's super helpful - my apologies for the late reply - just in a meeting but I have it working and will report back very soon! Thanks again - I'll write back in about an hour or so

Comment: @digitalHound I did the following to get this working - I left the prepareForSegue back to the setSelectedName and in the viewDidLoad, as you suggested, I placed the self.nameAddSearchBar.text = _selectedName; - the same worked if I did the viewWillAppear, but I'm happy to leave it in the viewDidLoad. Thanks so much for your help. I want to accept your answer but need a filled out answer - do you mind filling one out and I will accept it and up vote it? Thanks again

Comment: Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving

```
self.nameAddSearchBar.text = selectedName
```

from the setter (-setSelectedName) into viewDidLoad in TV2. The issue here is that you're trying to assign nameAddSearchBar (a view) before it has loaded.

Since the search bar is part of the "view", it is not be available until "viewDidLoad". You can set the selectedName property with the right value and then update the view (search bar.txt) with that value once the view is loaded (in viewDidLoad).